# Deploying my Java Dynamic Web Project to Heroku

Tags: heroku

I've been trying to deploy a dynamic web project created in Eclipse to Heroku but I've been having a few difficulties. This project does not use a pom file/maven and does not seem to work with any of the java buildpacks that I try to use. I added a jvm buildpack and this appeared to help my project pass deployment, but when I try to open my app, I get the following error:

"Application error
An error occurred in the application and your page could not be served. If you are the application owner, check your logs for details. You can do this from the Heroku CLI with the command
heroku logs --tail"

Is there a specific buildpack that I should use for this project?

Comment: Did you check the logs for details? What do they say?

Comment: I try to run the heroku logs command from the CLI but I end up getting this error :"ECONNRESET: tunneling socket could not be established, cause=getaddrinfo ENOTFOUND proxy.server.com"

Comment: Is that your proxy server there?

Comment: Yeah, looks like something was misconfigured.

Comment: It looks most java buildpacks require a pom file. If my web project does not use a pom file, what would be the best buildpack to use?